# How to use Polymer's core-card without using core-scaffold?

Tags: html, css, polymer

I need to use the `core-card` element of polymer but it appears it is not present as a single element so it can not be imported and used without using `core-scaffold`. Is there any other way or alternate element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what i used for my card elements was just a paper-shadow styled as a card.

```
  .card {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#000000;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:10pt;
    position:relative;
  }
  <paper-shadow z="1" class="card">
      // card content
  </paper-shadow>
```

maybe this will get you by. from what i read they are working on a standalone card element but it just isn't ready for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [swipeable-card](https://github.com/polymerlabs/swipeable-card) for the time being but, as pointed out in the previous answer, you can also just grab the markup from core-scaffold and use that :D